# REST service & X.509 client-side certificate

Tags: tomcat, rest, x509certificate

I have developed a REST service with Apache Jersey, running on Tomcat.

It works OK, but now I have to securize it using data obtained from a X.509 client certificate. I don't know where to start...

Could you guys give me some advices?? Thank you for your valuable help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starting point, you need Tomcat to perform certificate validation. There are tutorials on how to do that, [here](http://users.skynet.be/pascalbotte/art/clientcertconf.htm) and [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/ssl-howto.html).

Comment: If you just want to make sure that the data is encrypted and cannot be intercepted or tampered with during transmission, then you just need to configure the server certificate for 1-way SSL(and not worry about client certificates).  The SSL How-To should get you going.